# When moving, only one column of aliens spawn

Tags: python

I have been working through Python Crash Course and I have come across an issue. The goal is as follows:

- Have a fleet of aliens move from the right of the screen to the left of the screen.

The step before this was to create the fleet of aliens, which I managed to do. However, when I put in the code to move the aliens, only a single column of aliens appear on screen to move. I am struggling to figure out where I have made a mistake. Below are the relevant codes (unrelated codes are in reference to the bullets and ship):

settings.py

```
class Alien(Sprite):
    """ A class to represent the aliens."""

    def __init__(self, ss_game):
-- unrelated code -- 
        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        self.rect.right = self.screen_rect.right

        # Store the alien's exact horizontal and vertical positions.
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

    def update(self):
        """Move the alien to the left."""
        self.x -= self.settings.alien_speed
        self.rect.x = self.x
```

sideways_shooter.py

```
    def run_game(self):
        "Start the main loop for the game."
        while True:
            self._check_events()
            self.ship.update()
            self.bullets.update()
            self._update_aliens() # Removing this will make the full array appear on screen 
                                    motionless
            self._update_screen()

    def _update_screen(self):
        -- unrelated code --
        self.aliens.draw(self.screen)
        pygame.display.flip()

    def _create_fleet(self):
        """Create the fleet of aliens."""
        # Make an alien.
        alien = Alien(self)
        alien_height, alien_width = alien.rect.size
        available_space_y = self.settings.screen_height - alien_height
        number_aliens_y = available_space_y // alien_height

        # Determine the number of columns of aliens that fit on the screen.
        available_space_x = (self.settings.screen_width - (3 * alien_width))
        number_columns = available_space_x // (3 * alien_width)

        for column_number in range(number_columns):
            for alien_number in range(number_aliens_y):
                self._create_alien(alien_number, column_number)

    def _create_alien(self, alien_number, column_number):
        alien = Alien(self)
        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        alien_height, alien_width = alien.rect.size
        alien.y = (alien_height + 2 * alien_height * alien_number)
        alien.rect.y = alien.y
        alien.rect.x = self.screen_rect.right - (2 * alien.rect.width + 2 * alien.rect.width * column_number)
        self.aliens.add(alien)

    def _update_aliens(self):
        """Update the positions of all aliens in the fleet."""
        self.aliens.update()
```

alien.py

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Alien(Sprite):
    """ A class to represent the aliens."""

    def __init__(self, ss_game):
        """Initialise the alien and set its starting position."""
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = ss_game.screen
        self.settings = ss_game.settings

        # Load the alien image and set its rect attribute
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/alien.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        self.rect.right = self.screen_rect.right

        # Store the alien's exact horizontal and vertical positions.
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

    def update(self):
        """Move the alien to the left."""
        self.x -= self.settings.alien_speed
        self.rect.x = self.x
```

Any help would be very much appreciated! I am very new to programming, so I apologise if this code is largely unoptimized.

Thank you.

Dean

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `_create_alien()` method you're setting values for `alien.y`, `alien.rect.y`, and `alien.rect.x`.

You don't need to set `alien.y`, assuming the y-values of aliens in your sideways shooter game never change once they're created. But you do need to set the `alien.x` value, because that's what you're trying to control precisely.

Right now you're setting `alien.x` each time you make an alien instance, but that never gets redefined when the aliens is positioned. So when `update()` is called, every alien has the same `alien.x` value that was defined in `__init__()`. If you set `alien.x` in `_create_alien()`, I believe your fleet will behave correctly.